# Xamarin not resolving DialogViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am trying to use the DialogViewController in Xamarin but it cannot resolve it within Visual Studio. The same goes for RootElement, Section and EntryElement. Any idea why it doesn´t recognize these elements?
Using Xamarin.iOS 9.4.1.24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the MonoTouch.Dialog-1 assembly to your References.  It isn't included by default.